# The correct domain for canonical tag

Tags: tags

If my site domain is a naked domain (non-WWW). Should the canonical tag for my site be:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://mydomain.com/" />
```

or

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://mydomain.com/" /> ?
```

Comment: They're the same thing

Comment: Am I right to say, I can put either one of the canonical tag in the header.php?

Comment: @Jess he means that the two examples you wrote are literally identical, character for character. Did you mean to put "www" on the second one?

Answer (score 2):

You want the canonical URL to be the page you want to be considered the original URL for that content and what will be shown in Google's search results. In your case you will make sure your canonical URL does not use the www.